# How to login as root from Bash and do stuff

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, su, here-document

This is my simple bash:

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su - root -c /path/to/script.sh <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

But I get this error:

```
./test.sh
hello
su: must be run from a terminal
<current-user>
good bye
```

(OR)

```
cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
sudo su <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Again another error

(OR)

```
cat test3.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su root <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

again error...

when I try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
sudo -s <<EOF
<password>
echo Now I am root
id                                                                      
echo "yes!"
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Then the output is:

```
./script.sh
hello
[sudo] password for <user>:
```

I also changed my script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
expect "assword for user:"
send -- "password\r"
expect eof
```

and output is:

```
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
[sudo] password for user:
/bin/bash: <<EOF: command not found
```

Also `which sh` output is `/bin/sh`

How can I resolve the error in these three scripts?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616022/php-proc-open-su-must-be-run-from-a-terminal

Comment: when it asks you for a password, then give it your own password (not root password). If you run it again, it can cache the password and not ask again (depends on config). and remove `<password>` line

Comment: no...I don't want use caching...you are right..but for first time I want enter password and do stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe the password and send it in the command inside the script.

```
echo "password" | sudo -S
```

But it is not a good idea to send the password in the command line. If you need more information on how to login as root from the script, you can look at the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636840/changing-to-root-user-inside-shell-script).

However, if it is for experimental purposes, we can use the expect to enter the password from command line. The script needs be modified like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn sudo -s <<EOF 
expect "assword for username:" 
send -- "user-password\r" 
expect eof
```

The last line is needed since we need to press the Enter after inputting the password. As Tian suggested, it is not a good idea to send the root password in the shell script.

Comment: I update question

Comment: Is the option that I specified working?

Comment: No really, the error is:`sudo: root: command not found`

Comment: Take a look at this link. Apparently, you need the -s flag only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636840/changing-to-root-user-inside-shell-script

Comment: good..question: doesn't need to enter password?

Comment: Which flavor of Linux distribution you are using? My guess is, if it is debian based, sudo -s should not prompt you to enter the password. Anyways, it is worth trying the script in the link that I provided. If it is asking for password, then you might need to embed the password from command line as I had earlier posted, which is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: ubuntu..and please see UPDATE2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13110/discussion-between-ramesh-and-mortezalsc)

Comment: Ok see update2..I am in chat :)

Comment: sorry, how can I put message in chatroot? this is not enable for me!!!!!!I just see your comments

Comment: output of `which sh` >>> /bin/sh

Comment: If you are going to use the `-S` option with `sudo`, is a good idea to use `-k` too. This makes sure the password is not left on `stdin`, eg if the user has already recently entered in the parent shell.

Comment: yeah, but if we use `expect` do we need `-k` set?

Comment: Don't think so, AFAIK expect won't send anything if there is no password prompt

Comment: yeah, after expect I am using `send` to input the password in my script.

Answer (score 4):

Embedding the root password in the script isn't a good idea, from a security point of view, this is probably why su attempts to get it initially from a terminal.

Using `sudo` is a better route to take, it's more flexible, you can configure it to allow only particular commands, or even certain users to run a program/script with or without using a password (`man sudo`).

@Ketan's reference is also worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

**I GOT ANSWER FROM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862973/how-to-login-as-root-from-bash-and-do-stuff/21863534#21863534)**

Doing this kind of stuff is not safe or standard practice (in fact many consider it disasterous), it is really not a good idea to put a password in a script. A more standard approach would be simply to expect the whole script to be executed with root privileges, or just to have the script prompt for a password. You can also allow various commands to be run via sudo without a password by particular users by using the `NOPASSWD` option in `/etc/suoders`.

However, now that you are aware of the risks, it is possible to use `sudo -kS` to have sudo read the password from `stdin`:

```
sudo -kSs << EOF
password
whoami
echo "Not a good idea to have a password encoded in plain text"
EOF
```

Comment: Hmm, this answer looks familiar...

Comment: yes..I remove it.. and put it here and in superuser..ok?

Comment: really I put it here for helping others...I didn't want to bother you...please put the anser I'll remove it

Comment: No prob, maybe a link to the original would be good though. SE won't allow duplicate answers on the same question anyway, even if one is deleted.

Comment: Daresay this is a good answer, might as well upvote it :)

Comment: pretty good..I am thankful really...you can do it in superuser if you want :D

Comment: No, you go ahead. I don't really go on there anyway. I updated the original answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried /etc/sudoers?

```
your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

(edit with: sudoedit /etc/sudoers)
then, You will be able to run:

```
sudo /path/to/script without password
```