# C/C++: Running multiple commands as root

Tags: sudo, c

I want to execute commands within my C program. However, I need root priviliges to create some folders.
I run the following:

```
system("echo <rootpass> | sudo cd <folder> && make install");

<rootpass> is given by the user (and thus the command should only execute if the user has root priviliges).
```

However, when I run this, system returns with code 256 ( EPERM /* Operation not permitted */).

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `sudo` command doesn't 'chain' like that. You are invoking `cd` with `sudo` (or at least trying to - likely `cd` is a shell built in so that won't work anyway) but `make` will be run as the regular user. Regardless, this seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Always check your commands before embedding them in a system command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to write an script, which contains `expect` ,`sudo` and `make install` to solve your problem and your `system()` function call your script such as :

```
system("myscrip.sh");
```

For reading expect : [How to login as root from Bash and do stuff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/how-to-login-as-root-from-bash-and-do-stuff)