# Set the cpu frequency upon resuming from suspension?

Tags: power-management

On Ubuntu 14.04, I hope to set the cpu frequency upon resuming from suspension, so I created a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq` with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
        resume)
                sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c0
                sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c1
                ;;
        thaw)
                sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c0
                sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c1
                ;;
esac
```

But the cpu frequency isn't set upon waking up.  What might be the reason?

Can I run `sudo` command in the script? Will that require me to type in the password of root?

Thanks!

Comment: However it has security risk , But you can pass your password by `expect interpreter`

Comment: How shall I  pass my password by expect interpreter?

Comment: I think it's good link : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/how-to-login-as-root-from-bash-and-do-stuff